# addEventListener "remembers" that the person clicked on the button more than once, and then it REGISTERS TWICE after it registers once! How to fix?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I am using socket.io and writing a webRTC app. So what I have so far is that each user clicks the button "connect" and it connects them with another user who has also clicked connect. Now the connect button is disabled as the users are talking via video. 
Now, once one of the users clicks disconnect, the button connect gets available again, so it's not disabled anymore. 
BUT if the user clicks on connect right now, it goes through the function TWICE. It registeres TWICE, because it somehow remembered that the user clicked connect one time before. But I thought since it already registered that one time before, that it should be fine, and register just once yet again. But no! 
So nothing works at this point. Once the user clicks disconnect, and then connect again, then connect registers THREE TIMES. And so on. (I use debugger in chrome and I can see how many times it goes through the break points).

How can I make the addeventlistener function NOT remember all the previous clicks?
(stream is the media stream)

```
function justdoit(stream)
{
document.getElementById("connect").addEventListener("click",    function(e)
  { 
      document.getElementById("disconnect").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("connect").disabled = true;

      socket.on("quit", function(quit)  
      {
           justdoit(stream);
      });         


      document.getElementById("disconnect").addEventListener("click", function(e)
      {
           justdoit(stream);
      });
   });

}
justdoit(stream);
```

I didn't include all the code, just the code I thought was relevant. I obviously have quite a bit more code written than that, but I think it has something to do with the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding event listeners but you never remove them. Still, it may be even cleaner to try to avoid the recursive pattern you have of calling `justdoit` entirely, instead you could re-factor your code like this

```
(function init(stream) {
    // define functions
    // var connect = document.getElementById('connect'); // you can cache these
    function click_connect(e) {
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = false;
        // other connect actions
    }
    function click_disconnect(e) {
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = false;
        // other disconnect actions
    }
    // set up
    document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', click_connect);
    document.getElementById('disconnect').addEventListener('click', click_disconnect);
}(stream));
```

I left out your `socket.on("quit", ..` because I wasn't sure whether you need to re-register this (i.e. you'd do it in `click_connect` or `click_disconnect`) or if you only had to do it one time (do it in `// set up` region)

---

If you just want to know how to remove event listeners, you use [`target.removeEventListener(type, handler_reference)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), i.e.

```
var fn = function (e) {},
    elem = document.getElementById('foo');
elem.addEventListener('click', fn);
elem.removeEventListener('click', fn); // same handler ref as addEventListener
```